# Problem with sending Array of ArrayList to WebService as Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a array of `ArrayList` as shown below:

```
ArrayList[] m;
```

My web service method takes this type as parameter.

How can I send it to web service?

When I do so the Web Service changes my array of `ArrayList` to `Object[][]`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the service reference and change the "Collection Type"

It should be noted though, that ArrayList is seen as the same as Object[] in the proxy. Go to this website for more info:
[ArrayList is seen as object[] in the WCF methods return type](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/bc099a57-8918-4719-b060-2cfbf4e58d08)